# Decoding XML in a SQL Server column into rows in output

Tags: sql-server, xml

I've never actually come across XML in a SQL Server before - charmed I guess - and now I'm bootstrapping. Is there any way to query these columns and return results as if they were separate rows?

Here's an example of the data in one of the columns in one of the rows...

```
<X C="0" I="1">
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0" />
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0.03" />
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0.03" />
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0.03" />
</X>
```

I'd like to get something to the effect of:

```
row1col1 row1col2 "1Y0M0W0D" "0" "0"
row1col1 row1col2 "1Y0M0W0D" "0" "0.03"
row1col1 row1col2 "1Y0M0W0D" "0" "0.03"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [XML.nodes(...)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) in SQL to access XML as a record set.  If the data is a column and not a variable then use `CROSS APPLY [column].nodes(...)`.

```
DECLARE @xml XML = N'
<X C="0" I="1">
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0" />
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0.03" />
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0.03" />
  <E D="1Y0M0W0D" P="0" A="0.03" />
</X>
';

SELECT 
    x.e.value('../@C', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS [C]
    ,x.e.value('../@I', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS [I]
    ,x.e.value('@D', 'NVARCHAR(10)') AS [D]
    ,x.e.value('@P', 'INT') AS [P]
    ,x.e.value('@A', 'FLOAT') AS [A]
FROM @xml.nodes('/X/E') x(e)
```

Comment: Superb. You just saved me a whole lot of Googling. Not that I mind googling, but you know...